# Can't get the correct of a client ip in my node.js project

Tags: javascript, node.js, ip

I'm trying to get the ip of the clients who connects to my node server via a middleware, but for some reason, I only get the local ip. The project is hosted on a cloud platform, but all I get is 127.0.0.1. No matter if I connect to it, or my friend who lives in another country.

Code:

```
async function getUserIp(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.socket.remoteAddress);
  next();
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing something in my code, or if it is the environment itself on the web-hotel I use, hence why I only get local ip.

Answer (score 0):

Your hosting service has a reverse proxy between the node application and the Internet.

It runs on the same computer as the node application which is why requests from it come from 127.0.0.1.

It **might** forward the originating IP in an HTTP request header (such as [`X-Forwarded-For`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For)). Consult the documentation of your hosting service to find out if it does. (Alternatively deploy a version of your app that logs *all* request headers so you can look through them).